# Checking assumptions in confirmatory path analysis

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, assumptions, multivariate-normal-distribution, path-model

I performed a simple confirmatory path analysis using the R package [piecewiseSEM](http://jslefche.github.io/piecewiseSEM/articles/piecewiseSEM.html) . My sample size is very small, only 24 observations and 4 variables. Since it's a two-year field experiment, it's really 12 fields that were sampled twice under different crops and conditions , so I ran it as a multilevel model nesting plot in rotation sequence.

I'm new to path analysis/ SEM and want to make sure I have checked the assumptions correctly. I exported the residuals and performed a Mardia's test for multivariate normality for each of my two y variables, and got a qq plot using [MVN](http://cran.uni-muenster.de/web/packages/MVN/vignettes/MVN.pdf). They all look good.

Is this enough? It's very difficult for me to tell if there's any normality assumption for the raw variables as well as for the residuals. Also, the package doesn't generate predicted values so I don't know how I'd test for homogeneity of variance.

Thank you in advance,

Patricia